# Web API in MVC Project isn't hitting breakpoints ("symbols not loaded")

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, with an ASP.NET web api defined as an area in this project.  So the structure is the following:

```
MVC Web
   Controllers
   Views
   Areas
     API (web API)
       Controllers
```

The app works as expected.  However, I am having an issue with debugging.  I can put a debugger in the MVC controller, and it works as expected.  I cannot put a breakpoint in the web API controller, as I get "the breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."  I've been in the throes of it for some time, so it's probably a simple fix but I cannot figure it out.  Any ideas why I'm getting this problem with web API controllers, when I can debug an MVC controller?

Comment: I often find this when my assemblies I am trying to use are not compiling as I expected. Make sure you are compiling all your classlibs and doing rebuild all. HTH's  (BTW, I can hit my webapi controller debug with no issue so it's not fundamentally a problem I think)

Comment: If you're using IIS Express, try shutting it down and letting VS fire it back up after you "Rebuild" your solution.

Comment: For me, I had this problem when the WebApi project was not set as the startup project for the solution. Making my project the startup one solved the problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Until you find a permanent solution you can use the method `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` to force a break to occur on that line - just like a breakpoint:

```
public ActionResult IndexCheckInOut(string providerKey, DateTime? date = null)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();   
    return View("Index");
}
```

Here are some links to articles that might help you find a more permanent solution:

[**The breakpoint will not currently be hit**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1832287.aspx/1?The%20breakpoint%20will%20not%20currently%20be%20hit)

[**Stepping into ASP.NET MVC source code with Visual Studio debugger**](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/04/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger.aspx)

Comment: The last link was the solution.  The solution for me was to disable "enable just my code".

Comment: The last link worked for me as well, but I also had to clean and rebuild my project.

Comment: @Dowlers same for me. Just needed to clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 5):

Possible solution: I had forgotten that I was previously doing some remote debugging and had set debug symbols to be loaded from a UNC path instead of the Microsoft Symbol Servers.

To fix this head to: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> Make sure 'Microsoft Symbol Servers' is checked.

I also found this issue from creating a new Solution Configuration and not basing it on any existing configuration, such as the DEBUG configuration. That caused `Debug Info` to be set to `none`.

To fix this: Right-click your project -> Properties -> Build -> Make sure your faulty Solution Configuration is set -> click `Advanced` -> change `Debug Info` to `full`.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked out to just stop IIS and restart Visual Studio. Definitely worth a try before further investigation.

Answer (score 3):

Open:

Tools - Options - Debugging - General

Select:

- Enable .NET Framework source stepping
- Enable source server support (all options selected)

Open:

Tools - Options - Symbol

Select **Microsoft Symbol Servers**

Click **Load All Symbols**

Rebuild the project.

Select:

Clean

Rebuild

Rebuild solution and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue myself and was tearing my hair out for about an hour until I realised Visual Studio had mysteriously switched to run the project in 'Release' mode. Switching back to 'Debug' mode and rebuilding sorted me out.

Probably a very niche answer to this problem, but hopefully this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

- Close\Exit from all instances of `IIS Express` in the system tray (beside the Windows clock).
- Delete `bin` and `obj` folders in your project directory
- Restart Visual Studio
- Run it again

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but mine was related to the addition of a config Transform. Go to Build > Configuration Manager  under Active Solution Configuration make sure you have Debug selected.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the following

I had created a virtual directory in my IIS and use that name in my start URL link like
http://WebAPI/swagger/ui/index
(My symbols where not loaded with all the above steps)

1. Use IIS Express
2. Deleted the website from IIS Manager called WebAPI
3. Start URL I changed back to is http://localhost:59788/swagger/ui/index (Default port from visual studio)

Now all my symbols are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

if your debug worked and suddenly stopped working, the most common reason in my experience is problem in the IIS.

1. check that project->properties -> project URL is correct,
2. use IISReset to reset IIS

Answer (score 0):

`app.MapControllers()` was missing from program.cs

I only stumbled across this on a medium article, fortunately!!

(I’m using .net 7.0)

It was very odd because my first get-all sales were being returned, that only returned a simple entity type though!

Now I can clearly see 500 errors. For example, the AdventureWorks 2017 SalesOrderDetail table requires two integers for its primary key!