# I can't set breakpoint in c# class visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: **When I hover on break point **]

I can't set break point on handler please help me
the breakPoint

Comment: rebuild the solution

Comment: Add some more information. Does the project build? Do you have release or debug configuration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582022/visual-studio-breakpoints-not-being-hit