# Visual studio 2019 not debugging breakpoint?

Tags: debugging, model-view-controller, version, metadata, breakpoints

I'm making an ASP .NET project using MVC, I've been having a recurring glitch in visual studio when I try debugging recently added code, when I add a breakpoint to a method in which I have added new code and I try debugging that method, the debugger skips the new code and only debugs the old code. It's like the code stayed in an older version and visual studio won't detect new code. Any idea what this might be?

This is a method in which I have added new code as an example:

```
        public ActionResult EnviarCorreo()
        {
            bool num;

            num = false;

            if (num == true)
            { 
                clsCotizacion ObjCotizacion = new clsCotizacion();
                ViewBag.Lista = ObjCotizacion.ConsultaCorreoProveedor().ToList();
                return View();
            }
        return View("Index");
        }
```

The new code is:

```
bool num;

num = false;

   if (num == true)
        { 
        //the code inside this if is old
        } 
        return View("Index");
```

As you can see, if this were to be executed, the method wouldn't be able to run the code inside "if (num == true)" because I've set the value of num to false, yet the code is still executed because visualstudio skips the newly added code, so it jumps straight to "clsCotizacion ObjCotizacion = new clsCotizacion();".
I should also mention that when debugging step by step, the positions of the lines of the debugger are still the same as the ones in the old method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not actually be calling the new code, where the new breakpoints are.

This thread looks like a similar issue to yours as well: [Visual Studio breakpoints not being hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582022/visual-studio-breakpoints-not-being-hit)
see if that answers your question!

Comment: The solution configuration is set to Debug and the solution platform is set to any CPU, the new code is still not debugged or executed at all. I'll edit the original question to show an example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Today repaired, then uninstalled and completely re-installed Visual Studio, with no effect. Some functions are called, but methods in those functions are bypassed/skipped completely. Breakpoints are ignored. The same thing happened on VS 2017 Community after I went online while VS was processing data. Only clue was a popup advisory that said code blocks were bypassed "because of possible side effects." I updated to VS 2022 Community, and NEVER went online while it was processing data. Until a few days ago. Now VS is
malfunctioning again, bypassing code blocks, ignoring breakpoints, with no apparent reason. (Critical) output is unreliable and unpredictable. I have filed several "Report a Problem" requests to Microsoft (recently and several years ago, when problem first noticed), with no resolution or response.

The best solution I can think of (for me) is to migrate code to Java, switch to IntelliJ, and dump VS completely.